# How to remove/erase flash in the embedded devices(MX 6Dual/6Quad application processor)?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux

How to remove/erase nand flash flash in the embedded devices(MX 6 Dual/6 Quad application processor)?

I can connect to the hardware using putty and i was able to enter into the device in 2 different modes: Boot mode and normal mode(which shows the Linux file system).I need the hardware to allow only to connect to it boot mode.

Comment: We need more information to help you with this question. Start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide more information about your issue. Is that nand flash or eMMC flash?

Comment: Its eMMC flash                                                                            .

Comment: Saying remove is not the same as erase. See this [TI Wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Linux_Core_U-Boot_User%27s_Guide#Using_SD.2C_eMMC_or_USB_storage). eMMC usage should be the same from u-boot.